# Having trouble converting from curl request to Python

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

So I have the following curl request:

```
curl -F 'json={"method":"get_upload_status","params":{"token":"123","video_id":"456"}}' http://api.brightcove.com/services/post
```

And expect the response

```
{"error": {"name":"InvalidTokenError","message":"invalid token","code":210}, "result": null, "id": null}
```

And I'm trying to convert it to a python request, but the server I'm sending it to keeps returning an error that it can't find the json. Currently I'm trying

```
import requests
data = {'params': {'token': '123', 'video_id':'456'}, 'method': 'get_upload_status'}

requests.post(url='http://api.thesite.com/services/post', json=data)
```

But it keeps returning an error. I've tried multiple things including

```
# Attempt 1
requests.post(url='http://api.brightcove.com/services/post', data=data)

# Attempt 2
import json
requests.post(url='http://api.brightcove.com/services/post', data=json.dumps(data))

# Attempt 3
import json
requests.post(url='http://api.brightcove.com/services/post', json=json.dumps(data))
```

And basically all combinations of that all to no avail. There has to be something simply I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

data = {'json': json.dumps({'params': {'token': '123', 'video_id':'456'}, 'method': 'get_upload_status'})}

requests.post(url='http://api.thesite.com/services/post', data=data)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The server is now returning:
{u'id': None, u'result': None, u'error': {u'message': u"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of params", u'code': 205, u'name': u'MalformedParametersError'}}

Comment: Seems that your back-end trying to parse value in `json` key, I've edited answer.